# hide blue dot while retrieving google map current location in IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, currentlocation, gmsmapview

I am trying to add the default button to return to current Location within google map. I added the button using

```
self.mapView.myLocationButton = YES
```

But not able to hide the ***blue dot*** which is not required in my case.

***If i set***

```
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO
```

It would remove the functionality to return back to current Location on pressing the current Location button.

***Following is the code i've implemented***

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     self.mapView.delegate = self;

     self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
     self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the annotation view:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *note= [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    note.hidden = YES;
}
```

In this way the map will still receive user's location updates but the blue dot is hidden. Remember that since this is a delegate method, you should correctly set the delegate.

Comment: The question is about the GMSMapView and not the MKMapView.

Answer (score 2):

1. `self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO` to hide the blue dot.
2. set a class to implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to track user's location.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    self. mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
```

Comment: If you set the `showsUserLocation=NO` the Map will stop to track user's location and thus the myLocationButton will be unusable. You can check it in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation

Answer (score -1):

Easier way would be to replace your annotation with view that has color as clearColor. This way our current location would be shown with an invisible annotation ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use **mapView_.myLocationEnabled = NO;**

Its solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

In `Swift 4x` -

```
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

Comment: set `mapView.isMyLocationEnabled =  false`